# What are the system criteria for selecting the rarest badges in your profile?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, rarest-badges

I just see this profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982032/it-is-a-literature and in the *Rarest Bronze Badges* you can see:

- Benefactor
- Promoter
- Peer Pressure

And when I saw my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3653989/adrian-cid-almaguer?tab=profile in my *Rarest Bronze Badges* I only have:

- Synonymizer

Even when I have the three badges (Benefactor, Promoter, Peer Pressure) in my badges.

So, how does the system select the rarest badges in your profile?

I don't know what happened, but I have now three *Rarest Bronze Badges*:

- Synonymizer
- php
- Proofreader

Comment: [Main-meta dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254246/what-does-rarest-mean-on-the-badges-display)

Comment: @AakashM Thanks for the info, but why in my profile there are only one Bronze Rarest Badge when I have more Bronze Rarest Badges?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before the edit you were asking why your profile displays Synonymizer as a Bronze Rarest badge, when you've seen another profile displaying Benefactor, Promoter, Peer Pressure as Bronze Rarest badges.

The answer is easy - because Synonymizer  is *rarer* than Benefactor, Promoter, Peer Pressure! Look at [all the bronze badges for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=bronze) and you will see that Synonymizer has been awarded just 651 times, making it considerably rarer than Benefactor (24644 awards), Promoter (43564), Peer Pressure (74810). You should be much more proud (on a rarity basis) of having Synonymizer than of having Benefactor, Promoter, Peer Pressure, which is why the system picked that.

After the edit you point out that now you do have three Bronze Rarest badges displayed, but a completely different set. Again, the three you have displayed are all *rarer* than Benefactor, Promoter, Peer Pressure.

The rule is simple: **of all the badges you have, which are the three that have been awarded the least, across all users of the site**. For example, blowing my own trumpet for a moment, I have the bronze badge for [resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper), which only 11 people have ever been awarded, so it's shown as *my* rarest bronze badge.

Additionally, in general, things such as this are updated on a batch basis (that is, it's recalculated every so often, rather than immediately).

Comment: I guess I should be "really proud" of my [gold vba badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2193/vba), awarded only 6 times...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes! Congratulations!!

Comment: but, Why only one badge? When I have others?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I see three bronze rarest badges in your profile. Maybe the batch process was in the middle of updating your profile when you looked before.

Comment: @AakashM Only yesterday I can see 3 badges, When the new profile was installed I already had these badges that are now displayed, but only 1 was displayed until yesterday before my question. And other people had 3 badges. But maybe was the badge process.