# What is a "rare" badge?

Tags: support, profile-page, badges, rarest-badges

I noticed the following on the profile page of a relatively new user:

[image]

What is the definition of "rare" here?

---

In case it helps, the above notification only seems to be displayed for a user who has asked or answered at least one question - otherwise, the profile page seems to show only a generic "This user hasn't posted yet" placeholder.

And if they do have at least one badge, then we may see the following (although I would hope that "informed" is not a rarity):

[image]

Comment: As far as I remember, the badges were sorted by  a metric of how rare they were (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291748/what-are-the-system-criteria-for-selecting-the-rarest-badges-in-your-profile). It seems like with the new changes to the profile page, that option is gone. I think the wording is a leftover from that.

Comment: Thank you @ayhan I am sure that is it. The panel doesn't show "rare" badges - it just shows the rarest of those which have been awarded. Obvious in hindsight.

Comment: It's a badge that's the opposite of well done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close this out...

The placeholder text should not use the word "rare":

[image]

The panel doesn't show "rare badges" - it just shows the *rarest* badges (up to three badges, I think) of those which have been awarded to the user.

---

**Update**

This turns out to be an old Meta Stack Exchange question: [What are "rare" badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287093/what-are-rare-badges).

It is being revisited as part of the recent [responsive user profile changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile/371155#comment1239176_371155).